# How to Uninstall Ubuntu from my Secondary Disk to Install it in my Primary Disk?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

The context: recently, I started collaborating on a open-source project whose main application runs in Linux. I have a Notebook with a small SSD (128Gb) and a HD (1Tb) and I have always used Windows. So, I installed an Ubuntu in my HD and left the Windows on the SSD having to use dual boot.

I am changing this small SSD for a new larger one and I'll be installing Ubuntu on it as well, because it runs too slowly on the HD.

**What do I do in order to have an unique OS in the computer? I mean, if I install Ubuntu on the SSD and leave the HD as it is, I'll end up with two OS (one Ubuntu in the new SSD and another one in the HD).**

PS: I tried hard to come up with a good title for the question, but, although the situation seems basic, I couldn't find a better way to formulate the question.

Comment: Were I in your shoes, I would simply install Ubuntu onto the SSD. Then move your data across. Finally, after testing to ensure the new system is ready, wipe the HDD.

Comment: @user535733 Great, but (once again, I know it's basic) once the HDD is wiped (imagining the new system is ready an working) will it be possible to access it through the Ubuntu normally?

Comment: Will it be possible to access *what*? If you wipe the disk, there's nothing to access. Can you be more specific about what you're confused about. FWIW I agree with the suggestion that you should just reinstall the OS to the new hard drive. That's the easiest option.

Comment: What I meant was: Will the HDD be visible through the Ubuntu for me to use it normally (to store files, install programs, whatever) once it's formatted?

Comment: Yes of course. A formatted disk will behave exactly like a new one.